# Canvas with filled circle with a number

Tags: javascript, canvas

I use javascript (not jQuery).

### In short

- Filled circle
- Transparent behind the circle
- Number centered in the middle

**These values need to be easy to change:**

- Radius
- Background color
- Font size
- Font family

It should **not** care if the number will break the circle.

### Reason

The reason for me needing this is I have a Google map. It has a lot of markers with different numbers and colors. I found a script that works (in Chrome) but it needed [D3](https://d3js.org/) in order to work.

It seems like this is a simple task. That's why I hope I could leave [D3](https://d3js.org/) in this case.

[image]

### Update

Here is my current code. I've read some more and maybe it would be possible to do it with SVG. What ever works.

```
var karta = (function () {
    var fn = {};
    var map;
    var latitude;
    var longitude;
    var zoom;
    var cache = {};
    var colors = [];
    var height = 75;
    var width = 75;

    // Init
    fn.init = function(options) {
        console.log(options);

        markers = options.markers;
        latitude = options.latitude;
        longitude = options.longitude;
        zoom = options.zoom;
        colors = fn.setColors();

        fn.setMap();
        fn.setMarkers();

        console.log(options);
    };

    // Set map
    fn.setMap = function() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: zoom,
            center: {
                lat: latitude,
                lng: longitude
            },
            mapTypeId: 'satellite',
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
        });
    };

    // Set markers
    fn.setMarkers = function() {
        var mytest = '<svg height="32" width="32"><foreignObject width="32" height="32" x="16" y="16" transform="translate(-16,-16)"><div class="circle" style="background: blue; border-radius: 100%; text-align: center; line-height: 32px; font-size: 12px;"><span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;">180</span></div></foreignObject></svg>';

        var myurl = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + btoa(mytest);

        console.log(myurl);

        markers.forEach( function( point ) {
            fn.icon( point[0], function(src) {
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng( point[1], point[2] ),
                    map: map,
                    icon: {
                        url: myurl,
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 25),
                        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };

    // Set colors
    fn.setColors = function() {
        colors[65] = "E50000";
        colors[80] = "E52500";
        colors[95] = "E54A00";
        colors[110] = "E56F00";
        colors[125] = "E59400";
        colors[140] = "B79B00";
        colors[155] = "89A200";
        colors[170] = "5CA900";
        colors[185] = "2EB000";
        colors[250] = "00B700";
        return colors;
    };

    // Set circle
    fn.setCircle = function(svg, number) {
        var circles = svg.append('circle')
            .attr('cx', '27.2')
            .attr('cy', '27.2')
            .attr('r', '12')
            .style('fill', colors[number]);
        return circles;
    };

    // Set label
    fn.setLabel = function(svg, number) {
        var label = svg.append('text')
            .attr('dx', 27)
            .attr('dy', 32)
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('style', 'font-size: 12px; fill: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-weight: bold')
            .text(number);
        return label;
    };

    // Set svg
    fn.setSvg = function(number) {
        var svg = d3.select(document.createElement('div')).append('svg')
            .attr('viewBox', '0 0 54.4 54.4')
            .append('g')

        fn.setCircle(svg, number);
        fn.setLabel(svg, number);
        return svg;
    };

    // Set image
    fn.setImage = function(number, node, callback) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = (function(width, height) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var dataURL;

            d3.select(canvas)
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height);

            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            generateIconCache[number] = dataURL;

            callback(dataURL);
        }).bind(this, width, height);

        var xmlSource = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(node);
        image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(encodeURIComponent(xmlSource).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
        }));
    };

    // Icon
    fn.icon = function( number, callback ) {
        if( cache[number] !== undefined ) {
            callback( cache[number] );
        }

        var svg = fn.setSvg(number);
        var node = svg.node().parentNode.cloneNode(true);

        d3.select(node).select('clippath').remove();

        fn.setImage(number, node, callback);
    }

    return fn;
})();
```

Comment: Do you have an example or a link of your current script that uses D3.js?

Comment: @YannickBlondeau I added my whole code.

Comment: You can draw a filled circle with `context.arc( centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2)` and `context.fill()`. You can draw text centered in your arc with `context.textAlign = 'center'; context.textBaseline = 'middle'` and `context.fillText('24', centerX, centerY)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Scaling text to fit a circle.

To scale text to fit a circle you need to find the angle of the diagonal line across the text. To get that you need the font height and the font width. The font height is in the font attribute of the 2D context. Eg "18px Arial" and the font width can be calculated using the 2D context `textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width`.

once you have the font width and the font height you can get the diagonal angle with `textDiag = Math.atan(fontheight / fontWidth)` . This will be the angle where on the circle the corner of the text will touch the side.

We can draw a line from that point on the circle circumference to the horizontal line through the middle of the circle to give us the location of right edge of the text. You get that with `halfWidth = Math.cos(textDiag) * radius` The total text width should be twice that.

As it is a real pain to find a point size to match a given text width, it is easier just to scale the text using the context transformation matrix.

The scale is simply the required text width divided by then known text width. `fontScale = halfWidth * 2) / textWidth` then set the transform `ctx.setTransform(fontScale,0,0,fontScale,r,r)` (r is the radius or center of circle) and draw the text `ctx.filltext(text,0,0)` with the textAlign and textBaseline 2d context attributes set to `"center"` and `"middle"` respectively

The example show this in action by creating a simple text circle img that can be drawn on another canvas, or just added to the DOM as an image. The two properties number and radius set the number to display and the size in pixels. The demo shows it being created and drawn onto a canvas with the number increasing to show how it scales.

```js
// creates a circle image object 
// Function arguments.
// radius is the you know ....
// number is the value to display in the circle
// style is this style 
//    style.color   the circle colour. Defaults to  "red";
//    style.font  the font. Defaults to  '18px arial';
//    style.fontColor is the font colour. Defaults to "white";
//    style.fit if true then the number is made to fit te circle as best it can. Defaults to true
//    style.decimals number of decimal places to display. Defaults to 0
// 
// returns 
// Html canvas element with the following custom attributes
//    ctx the 2D context
//    number the value to display
//    radius the radius
//    displayStyle the referance to the style arrgument passed when createCircleNumberImage
//                was called
//    draw the function used to render the image. This function has no arguments 
//        use the displayStyle atrribute to set the style


function createCircleNumberImage(radius,number,style){
    // create HTML 5 image element
    img = document.createElement("canvas");
    // size it
    img.width = Math.ceil(radius * 2);
    img.height = Math.ceil(radius * 2);
    // get a drawing context
    img.ctx = img.getContext("2d");
    
    // set custom attributes
    img.radius = radius;
    img.number = number;
    img.displayStyle = style;
    
    // set defaults
    style.color = style.color ? style.color : "red";
    style.font = style.font ? style.font : '18px arial';
    style.fontColor = style.fontColor ? style.fontColor : "white";
    style.fit = style.fit === undefined ? true : style.fit;
    style.decimals = style.decimals === undefined || isNaN(style.decimals) ? 0 : style.decimals;
    
    // add draw function
    img.draw = function(){
        var fontScale, fontWidth, fontSize, number;
        // resize
        this.width = Math.ceil(this.radius * 2);
        this.height = Math.ceil(this.radius * 2);
        // clear (incase resize did not do it) 
        this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.width,this.height);
        
        // draw the circle
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.displayStyle.color;
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(radius,radius,radius,0,Math.PI * 2);
        this.ctx.fill();
        
        // setup the font styles
        this.ctx.font = this.displayStyle.font;
        this.ctx.textAlign = "center";
        this.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.displayStyle.fontColor;
        
        // get the value to display
        number = this.number.toFixed(this.displayStyle.decimals);
        
        // get the font size
        fontSize = Number(/[0-9\.]+/.exec(this.ctx.font)[0]);
        if(!this.displayStyle.fit || isNaN(fontSize)){ // Dont fit text or font height unknown
            this.ctx.fillText(number,radius,radius);
        }else{ 
            // fit font as based on the angle from text center to bottom right
            fontWidth = this.ctx.measureText(number).width;
            fontScale = Math.cos(Math.atan(fontSize/fontWidth)) * this.radius * 2 / fontWidth;
            this.ctx.setTransform(fontScale,0,0,fontScale,this.radius,this.radius);
            this.ctx.fillText(number,0,0);
            this.ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // restor the transform
        }
        
        if(!this.displayStyle.fit || isNaN(fontSize)){ // Dont fit text or font height unknown
             this.ctx.fillText(number,radius,radius);
        }else{ 
             fontScale = Math.cos(Math.atan(fontSize/fontWidth)) * this.radius * 2 / fontWidth;
             this.ctx.setTransform(fontScale,0,0,fontScale,this.radius,this.radius);
             this.ctx.fillText(number,0,0);
             this.ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // restor the transform
        }
        // return this so you can call the draw function from within a canvas drawImage function
        return this;
    }
    // draw first time
    img.draw()
    // return new image
    return img;
}



var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 320;
canvas.height = 200;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);



// set comments above the function declaration for help
var sun =  createCircleNumberImage (
    60,1,{
        fontColor : "white",
        font : "24px arial",
        color : "#EE0",
        fit : true,
        decimals : 0,
    }
)


function doAgain(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height/2)
    ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
    ctx.fillRect(0,canvas.height /2 ,canvas.width,canvas.height/2)

    if(sun.number > 5000000000){
        sun.number = 0;
    }
    sun.number = sun.number + Math.floor(sun.number/10) + 1;
    ctx.drawImage(sun.draw(),ctx.canvas.width / 2 - sun.radius,ctx.canvas.height / 2 - sun.radius);
    setTimeout(doAgain,200);
}
doAgain();
```

Comment: I think you'll hate me, but you know the `textBaseline` thing... [Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1BEyV.png) and [chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0NmAB.png)

Comment: @kaiido Maybe FF should try fitting in with the more popular browsers. It is not my concern that FF does not comply https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-textbaseline show clearly where the base line is and not what MDN wants it to be "**middle**
The text baseline is the middle of the em square." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline#Options nor will I add vendor specific code for non complying browsers, that is up to the content creator (if they can be bothered)..

Comment: Actuallly FF does comply with specs. Chrome doesn't. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737852 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=607053 Ps: MDN is a user maintained wiki, it's not FF devs who write it.

Comment: I like the depth of the answer. I can't use it because of the poor browser support. I will probably go for something simpler like http://jsfiddle.net/DKcpS/ or http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Canvas_How_to/Text/Draw_text_inside_a_circle.htm Thanks!

Comment: @JensTörnell `Math.atan` and `Math.cos` are supported by all the browsers, and the two example you cite have the same browser support as any canvas rendering code. I am do not understand why you think this example has poor browser support?